# EXCEPTION: mammoth is not defined

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm, node-modules, mammoth

I am trying to integrate mammoth npm library with meteor.

When using the import command,
***import { mammoth } from "mammoth";*** was getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

When using the command,
***declare var mammoth: any;*** was getting

> EXCEPTION: mammoth is not defined

The code I am using is

```js
this.readFileInputEventAsArrayBuffer(event, function(arrayBuffer) {
      mammoth
        .convertToHtml({ arrayBuffer: arrayBuffer })
        .then(function(result: any) {
          var html = result.value; // The generated HTML
          var messages = result.messages; // Any messages, such as warnings during conversion
          // console.log('html: ' + html);
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
          var elements = document.getElementById("output").children;
          console.log(elements);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(elements));
          console.log(elements.length);
          for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            console.log(i + " --- ");
            console.log(elements[i]);
            var data = elements[i].innerHTML;
            // elements[i].setAttribute("draggable","true");
          }
        })
        .done();
      console.log(
        "event in fileUpload-readFileInputEventAsArrayBuffer" + event
      );
    });
```

```js
 readFileInputEventAsArrayBuffer(event, callback) {
    var file = event.target.files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(loadEvent: any) {
      var arrayBuffer = loadEvent.target.result;
      console.log("arrayBuffer: ");
      console.log(arrayBuffer);
      callback(arrayBuffer);
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }
```

When using the import

***declare var mammoth: any;***

getting the error

```
ReferenceError: mammoth is not defined
at app.component.ts:75
at FileReader.reader.onload (app.component.ts:109)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (modules.js:22723)
at Object.onInvoke (modules.js:57096)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (modules.js:22722)
at Zone.runGuarded (modules.js:22607)
at FileReader.<anonymous> (modules.js:22585)

Uncaught ReferenceError: mammoth is not defined
at app.component.ts:75
at FileReader.reader.onload (app.component.ts:109)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (modules.js:22723)
at Object.onInvoke (modules.js:57096)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (modules.js:22722)
at Zone.runGuarded (modules.js:22607)
at FileReader.<anonymous> (modules.js:22585)
```

When using the import

***import { mammoth } from "mammoth";***

getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
at meteorInstall.node_modules.mammoth.lib.docx.files.js (modules.js?hash=cd1f432…:83272)
at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:191)
at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:116)
at meteorInstall.node_modules.mammoth.lib.docx.docx-reader.js (modules.js?hash=cd1f432…:82091)
at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:191)
at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:116)
at meteorInstall.node_modules.mammoth.lib.index.js (modules.js?hash=cd1f432…:81954)
at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:191)
at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:116)
at meteorInstall.client.imports.app.app.component.js (app.component.ts:12)
at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:191)
at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:116)
at meteorInstall.client.imports.app.index.js (index.ts:1)
at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:191)
at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:116)
at meteorInstall.client.main.js (main.ts:5)
at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:191)
at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:116)
at demo.collection.ts:4
```

Please help in this.

> P.S.: When running as a angular project, it is working fine. Facing
>   the issue, when doing it in angular-meteor project.

Comment: How are you importing the mammoth lib into your page?

Comment: try `import mammoth from "mammoth";`?

Comment: @Alex, when I import using that, getting this **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined**. My doubt is whether the integration/usage of mammoth library supported in meteor?

Comment: please note no `{` and `}` in my example

Comment: @Raven, I am importing the mammoth lib by trying the following, 

`import { mammoth } from "mammoth";
import mammoth from "mammoth";
declare var mammoth: any;
var mammoth = require("mammoth");`

Comment: I tried that as well @Alex. Tried the above four ways of importing. Nothing is working. Is there any workaround for this. Was some node library files not supported by meteor?

Comment: I think the error is elsewhere, you are looking at wrong place. What line is that error getting throwed on? Search for places where you have `.bind` if any

Comment: Where is this code? It sounds like you need to inject mammoth into whatever this code is in order to have access to it.

Comment: @MikeFeltman, I am inserting this code in the same component .ts file and calling the function from the html code of the same component.

Comment: Ok, have you injected mammoth into the component?

Comment: Yes @MikeFeltman. i injected the mammoth into the meteor component using the above code. was there any other way to import the mammoth npm or if we run it in server side instead of the client, will it do?

Comment: Hi all, Any help in this?

Answer (score 2):

Try and see if this works: `import 'mammoth/mammoth.browser';` (browser build)

Or if you can may want to do this on the front-end, then you can use then include the following scripts onto your html page and do it on runtime. (Converting doc to html and rendering)

- As, also shown in this article -> https://mike.zwobble.org/projects/mammoth/

Script to be included:

- demo.js -> https://mike.zwobble.org/static/projects/mammoth/demo.js
- mammoth.browser.min.js -> https://mike.zwobble.org/static/projects/mammoth/mammoth.browser.min.js

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code of the mammoth npm package, you will see that there is no 'mammoth' nor default exported. It does, however, export each of the methods, so you can do it like this:

```
import {convertToHtml} from "mammoth";

convertToHtml({path: "path/to/document.docx"})
    .then(function(result){
        var html = result.value; // The generated HTML 
        var messages = result.messages; // Any messages, such as warnings during conversion 
    })
    .done();
```

That should do the trick :)

Comment: Hi Mikkel,

Thanks for the answer. But even for this, I am facing the below error.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
    at meteorInstall.node_modules.mammoth.lib.docx.files.js (modules.js?hash=ee5060b…:83272)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:191)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:116)
    at meteorInstall.node_modules.mammoth.lib.docx.docx-reader.js (modules.js?hash=ee5060b…:82091)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:191)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:116)
`

Comment: `at meteorInstall.node_modules.mammoth.lib.index.js (modules.js?hash=ee5060b…:81954)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:191)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:116)
    at meteorInstall.client.imports.app.app.component.js (app.component.ts:3)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:191)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:116)
    at meteorInstall.client.imports.app.index.js (index.ts:1)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:191)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:116)`

Comment: `at meteorInstall.client.main.js (main.ts:5)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:191)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=637cb12…:116)
    at demo.collection.ts:4`

Comment: any alternate approach/help in this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to import like this:
**`import {convertToHtml} from 'mammoth/mammoth.browser';`**

Inside componet.ts file:

```
import {convertToHtml} from "mammoth/mammoth.browser";
                   

convertToHtml({ arrayBuffer: arrayBuffer })
.then(function(result){
    var html = result.value; // The generated HTML
    var messages = result.messages; // Any messages, such as warnings during conversion
})
.done();
```

Above code worked for me in angular 9.